# How to check if the view controller is in peek mode [3d touch] or full screen mode in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, 3dtouch

The detail view controller supports peek mode. when we display the detailed controller in peek mode, we need to disable the tooltips/tutorial in detail controller. How do we identify if the view controller is shown in peek mode or full screen mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate your view controller in the `UIViewControllerPreviewing` delegate method, you can set a variable that tells it what context it is in.Then respond accordingly inside of your view controller code.

```
public func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    //...

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "DocumentViewer", bundle: nil)
    guard let detailViewController = 
        sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DocumentViewerViewController") 
        as? DocumentViewerViewController else { return nil }

    detailViewController.isPeeking = true // <--- Set variable here

    // Other stuff here...

    detailViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 380.0)
    previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

    return detailViewController
}
```

Then, inside of the detail view controller, enable/disable whatever you need.

Answer (score 5):

There is a not perfect but practical way to do that. In many cases `UINavigationController` and/or `UITabBarController` is used only except peek mode. You can identify peek mode by this.

```swift
let isPeeking = navigationController == nil
// or
let isPeeking = tabBarController == nil
```

Comment: I've recently found out the hard way that the `navigationController` property becomes `nil` if you start the interactive pop gesture then cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to determine that, but you when you set your peek `preferredContentSize` in method  `func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController?` you can set an observer for your view's width.

Then refer to your view controller's width. If it is the same as your preferredContentSize (or less than the UIScreen width) it is in peek mode, otherwise it has popped.

Answer (score 0):

You can check height of your peeking view controller with screen size

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

   let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
   if view.frame.height == screen.height { 
      // NOT peek mode
   } else {
      // Peek mode
   }

}
```

Comment: How can you even be sure that the view's height will be the screen's?